# using strong induction that there exists an integer $C$ that for all $D\ge C$ it is possible to return exactly $D$ by using only $2$ and $5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, transfinite-induction

Prove using strong induction that there exists an integer $C$ that for all $D \ge C$ it is possible to return exactly $D$ by using summed composites of only $2$ and $5$

so far i believe that $\exists C$, $\forall D$  $P(c,d)$ is true $\implies d = 2c+5c$, but i am not sure if thats the correct approach. Once I understand the base step then the process becomes more simplified. But as of now, I am unable to get beyond this point. I am unable to understand what it wants,

my base step would be

$P(1,7)---> 7 = 2(1)+5(1)$
is $c\le d$, yes $1 \le 7$
but i am having doubts on the next step following this

does the question want a logically reasoned methodology? what does it want?

Comment: Show 7 = 2+5; 8 = 4*2 + 0*5.  Then show if you can do $d = 2c+5d$ then you can do $d+2 = 2(c+1) + 5d$.  So this is true for all $7+2m$ or for $8+2m$.

Comment: What do you mean by "summed composites of only $2$ and $5$" exactly? Because I think you mean that you can get $d$ by ADDing to $c$, summed composites of only $2$ and $5$, for example if $c=4$ and $d=8$ then $d=c+2(2)+5(0)$

Comment: @AshwinSarith If you're looking for the sum of only non-negative multiples of $2$ and $5$, then this seems to be a case of the [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: @FareedAF hey, the question really is like for example you have d dollars, can you get d dollars using the sum of only 2s and 5s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from your comment, you're trying to prove that any positive integer $d$ can be written as $d=2a+5b$ where $a$ and $b$ are also positive integers.

If this is the question then the answer is yes for $d > 3$.

If $d$ is even then $d=2k$ so take $a=k$ and $b=0$

If $d$ is odd then $d=2k+1$ with $k\ge 2$, so for example if $d=5$ then it is true $d=2(0)+5(1)$, now let's suppose it is true up to $d'$ (i.e. $\exists a',b' \ge 0$ such that $d'=2a'+5b'$) and lets prove that the statement is true for $d= d'+2$ (since $d$ is also odd), $d=d'+2=2a'+5b'+2= 2(a'+1)+5b'$, so $a=a'+1$ and $b=b'$